# Codenameone google map

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a google map. In the simulator, everything works fine but in android device never finds the current location (shows message Location Error - see code). The map opens in world view...

```
cnt = new MapContainer(new GoogleMapsProvider(""));
cnt.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

LocationManager locationManager = LocationManager.getLocationManager();

InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
Dialog ipDlg = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
Location loc = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getCurrentLocationSync(30000);
ipDlg.dispose();
if (loc == null) {
    try {
        loc = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getCurrentLocation();
    } catch (IOException err) {
        Dialog.show("Location Error", "Unable to find your current location, please be sure that your GPS is turned on", "OK", null);
        return;
    }
}
locationManager.setLocationListener(this);

if (loc != null) {
    double lat = loc.getLatitude();
    double lng = loc.getLongitude();
    Coord coordinate = new Coord(lat, lng);
}
```

The GPS is active on the device.
I can see my location in other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve your code by falling back to some default locations if GPS reception is not good in a particular area:

```
cnt = new MapContainer(new GoogleMapsProvider(""));
cnt.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

LocationManager locationManager = LocationManager.getLocationManager();
Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(); //default
if (locationManager.isGPSDetectionSupported()) {
    if (locationManager.isGPSEnabled()) {
        InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
        Dialog ipDlg = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
        Location loc2 = locationManager.getCurrentLocationSync(30000);
        if (loc2 != null) {
            loc = loc2;
        }
    } else {
        Dialog.show("Location Error", "Unable to find your current location, please be sure that your GPS is turned on", "OK", null);
    }
} else {
    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
    Dialog ipDlg = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
    Location loc2 = locationManager.getCurrentLocationSync(30000);
    if (loc2 != null) {
        loc = loc2;
    } else {
        loc = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getCurrentLocation();
    }
}
if (loc != null) {
    double lat = loc.getLatitude();
    double lng = loc.getLongitude();
    Coord coordinate = new Coord(lat, lng);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The default location worked. It's taking a very long time to open the form with the map...20/30 sec...is it normal? if I go back form and re-enter takes even more time...it's showing the infinite progress so i think it's taking a very long time to find the location...

Comment: I forgot to mention that this process should be done in `postShow()` and not in `beforeShow()`

Comment: Also, avoid using InfiniteBlocking, it annoys users. What I usually do is add the InfiniteProgress to the Toolbar top-right or anywhere else and remove it once the process is done.

Comment: I have a class extend form so the code is in start(). I changed the code to show the form (this.show() ) after the creation of the map. Now it opens the form in a world view and takes the time showing the location...is it normal to take a long time to get the location?

Comment: In that case, wrap the above code in `callSerially()`... Something like this `Display.getInstance().callSerially(() ->{ //above code});`  or in the showListener of your form...`form.addShowListener()`